# Python discord-webhook value

Tags: python, discord, webhooks

I am trying to send a message in a discord channel with the discord-webhook module, but the `value=` has to be a variable and not a simple text.

My code:

```
available = 10
unavailable = 20

webhook = DiscordWebhook(url="example-url")
embed = DiscordEmbed(title=name+" / "+style, color=242424)
embed.set_author(name="Alert")
embed.add_embed_field(name="Available Sizes:", value=available)
embed.add_embed_field(name="Unavailable Sizes:", value=unavailable)
embed.set_timestamp()

webhook.add_embed(embed)
response = webhook.execute()
```

Unfortunately I always get this error message, because it is not a `"text"`:

```
[1/1] Webhook status code 400: {"embeds": ["0"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
value=str(available)
```

same for the other value

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does.